# Math symbols insertion in AUCTeX

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

I've been facing some trouble with math symbol insertion in AUCTeX and I'm probably missing something from the available structure and options. But as I'm struggling for a while, I might as well ask.

I know `LaTeX-math-mode`, I enable it, and I (think I) know how it is supposed to work. However, I'm in a sort of middle ground, as I don't use math heavily, so that the bindings beyond `LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix` don't really stick, but I do need it sometimes. Besides, many (most?) symbols in `LaTeX-math-default` have their binding set to `nil`.

I also know that, failing the binding I can recur to the menu `LaTeX-math-mode` provides. But I don't find menus very convenient in general, and prefer to avoid them, if at all possible.

I yet know that completion (with "C-M-i", aka "poor man's M-TAB") works in math mode. Which helps already, if I happen to know how the command starts. But, suppose I want to choose among any number of arrows...

So, as far as I can grasp, the insertion of math symbols from the set `LaTeX-math-default` and `LaTeX-math-list` will depend either, on the binding following the math-prefix (if there is one), on completion with "C-M-i" or, as a last resource, on the menu.

Still, I would expect to find the items of `LaTeX-math-default` and `LaTeX-math-list` available among the items of `TeX-insert-macro` (the usual `C-c RET`), but they don't seem to be available there. Which I find curious, since, e.g. the style file for "amssymb" includes it's items in the `TeX-add-symbols` section. So, if I load `amssymb`, I will find `\upharpoonright` available with `TeX-insert-macro`, but not `\ldots` or `\sum`.

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something? Are those symbols not available there because they are not supposed to be there, as there is a better way to reach them? Is there a configuration that I've missed to make them available there?

Finally, if my expectation is not unreasonable, how could I properly include the items in `LaTeX-math-default` and `LaTeX-math-list` among the candidates of `TeX-insert-macro`?

Some relevant items in my AUCTeX configuration (under `use-package`):

```
:hook (LaTeX-mode . LaTeX-math-mode)
:custom
(TeX-auto-save t)
(TeX-parse-self t)
(TeX-complete-expert-commands t)
(TeX-insert-macro-default-style (quote mandatory-args-only))
(LaTeX-math-abbrev-prefix "C-$")
(TeX-electric-math (cons "\\(" "\\)"))
```

Environment: AUCTeX 12.1.2, Emacs 26.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've made some progress on this and I might as well share.

The LaTeX default math symbols contained in `LaTeX-math-default` really seem not to be loaded to the completion list of `TeX-insert-macro` by default. I haven't followed the code in detail, but I have tested it with `emacs -Q`.

This indeed seems to be by design, out of the concern not to bloat the completion lists of `TeX-insert-macro`. ([This thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2019-04/msg00009.html) suggests this concern exists).

Now, I personally think this concern is more relevant in the context of the default completion framework, but less so if you happen to use some other completion framework, such as `ivy` or `helm`, which can deal better with a larger number of candidates (not unlimited though, of course).

I haven't found any standard way to include the items in `LaTeX-math-default` and `LaTeX-math-list` to `TeX-symbol-list` which is used to generate candidates by `TeX-insert-macro`.

But I did it with:

```
;; Math mode is nice, but it would be nicer to have math symbol completion
;; with 'TeX-insert-symbol' ("C-c RET").  I’m probably missing something,
;; but this should work until I learn the proper way to do it.
(defun my/auctex-add-math-to-TeX-symbol-list ()
  "Add math symbols in `LaTeX-math-default' to `TeX-symbol-list'.
Also those eventually in `LaTeX-math-list'. "
  (apply 'TeX-add-symbols
         (seq-filter 'stringp
                     (append (mapcar #'cadr LaTeX-math-list)
                             (mapcar #'cadr LaTeX-math-default)))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my/auctex-add-math-to-TeX-symbol-list)
```

There it is, in case someone else also thinks this is an interesting approach.